# Multiple Pickers leading to other picker options

Tags: swift, picker

Im trying to find a youtube tutorial explaining this exact thing I want to create but I can't.  The basic idea is to have a car drop down where the options change based on the previous selected item and after all those strings are picked then you can side by side compare both vehicles in MPG, Resale score etc.

I found an article online and it said this is the coding they used

example of what I am trying to create:

```
Cars: Honda (selected in picker view)
Model: (all the options made by Honda populate) in next picker
Year: (years those cars were made) in next picker
```

The code format they used...does that mean I need to make a huge data base for every possible scenario of cars I want to compare inside the code?  Im a new student learning swift so I may be over my head in what im trying to create.

```
{ make1: {model1: {year1, year2, … }, model2: {year1, year2, …}, …}, make2: {…}, …}
```

Comment: Yes, you need all of the data you need to show. How else would the data appear?

Comment: I get that I would need the code, but the format she has it written in is what confused me... wouldn't I be able to make it:

Comment: wow thats going to be a lot of data entry to make this, I thought there would be some shortcut to pull this up.  Thanks, I will get working on making it

Comment: Do not put that data in your code. Put it in a plist or a database.